# How to read .reqIf file?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have a requirement where I want to read the .reqIf file, since it is an XML file, i try reading it using SaxT, but in my eventReader I get nothing as the output.
Do we have an example of some kind from where I can get a hint as to how to read that type of file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the RMF framework:
[RMF framework](http://www.eclipse.org/rmf/)

It allows you to parse ReqIF files and convert them to an Eclipse EMF model.
Hope that helps.